# Linq updating a database, primary key

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables.  Document table and Version table.  Both are identicle except the version table has an ID field and a documentID field.  The document table has a documentId field.

I can correctly find the document but I cannot find the version table information because the id I am padding in it is trying to find this on the id field instead of the documentId field.

```
public ActionResult ApproveDocument(int id = 0)
    {
        IPACS_Document ipacs_document = db.IPACS_Document.Find(id);
        IPACS_Version ipacs_version = db.IPACS_Version.Find(id);

        ipacs_version.dateApproved = System.DateTime.Now;
        ipacs_version.approvedBy = User.Identity.Name.Split("\\".ToCharArray())[1];

        ipacs_document.dateApproved = System.DateTime.Now;
        ipacs_document.approvedBy = User.Identity.Name.Split("\\".ToCharArray())[1];
        ipacs_document.revision = ipacs_version.revision;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Approve");
    }
```

So the `ipacs_document` is found correctly because the id passed in 11 works.  However `ipacs_version` doesn't find anything because it is trying to find `id 11` instead of `documentId 11`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the .Find(id) method... did you write it or was it autogenerated?

Comment: It is auto generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering on how to use `Find` (DbSet<>) to engage `composite keys`...

> The Find method takes an array of objects as an argument. When working
>   with composite primary keys, pass the key values separated by commas
>   and in the same order that they are defined in the model.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.103).aspx

```
db.IPACS_Version.Find(id, documentid); // mind the order
```

And for anything more complex keep in mind that you could always use Linq queries, `Where` e.g.

```
db.IPACS_Version.Where(x => x.Id == id && x.DocumentId == docid && x.Flag == true);
```

> **Note:** You could use the `query`, `Where` (regardless of how your entities are made) -
>   **but if your `keys` are not set up properly** (based on the comments) - I'd discourage you to go that way. Instead
>   of a fast fix, make sure your tables, pk-s are set up as they should -
>   as that's essential. Then you can see which query is best for you (or
>   just use Find if that's all you need).

Comment: Hrm I wonder if the database was not set up correctly then.  The version table only has a single primary key, which is attached to ID.

Comment: probably is then James. Just upload the entities you're using - I can help with that too.

Comment: If it's code-first that is - I'm assuming it is, but doesn't have to be of course.

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out with some suggestions by you, testing it now.  But have updated the original post with the new code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll make sure the pk's are set up properly and try and continue from there. :)